# Specflow Tests to Make Pass (Green )in Jenkins if Ignored or Pending test found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, specflow, specrun

I m running specflow tests in Jenkins and everytime when test is pending/ Ignored/ Inconclusive it is making whole test suite to be fail (Like Red Jenkins build). How can i eliminate that to happen and make the Jenkins build green ?

Note:- We are executing tests with Cmdline in jenkins and it is as below .

```
@pushd %~dp0

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  "******".Tests.csproj"

@if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end

@cd ..\packages\SpecRun.Runner.*\tools

@set profile=%1
@if "%profile%" == "" set profile=Default

SpecRun.exe run %profile%.srprofile "/baseFolder:%~dp0\bin\Debug" /log:specrun.log /filter:%2 /report:TestResults\%3

:end

@popd
```

is there anything we have to do with Error level ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpecRun returning exit code 120 with @ignore tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845018/specrun-returning-exit-code-120-with-ignore-tests)

Comment: See the linked question, its answer is what you need.

Comment: @PaulHicks you means of doing it like 

    SpecRun.exe run %profile%.srprofile "/baseFolder:%~dp0\bin\Debug" /log:specrun.log /filter:%2 /report:TestResults\%3

if errorlevel 210 exit /b %errorlevel%

exit /b 0

:end

or

in 3rd line i means after MsBuild.exe?

Comment: That answer says that return code (errorlevel) greater than or equal to 200 is what you want to have appear as red in Jenkins, and 199 or less is what you want to have appear as blue / green in Jenkins. How you make that happen is up to you. That answer gives you a suggestion.

Comment: @PaulHicks Finally it works.. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I think SpecFlow needs to be fixed to conform to expected command-line usage!